# Error in println... EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) swift

Tags: swift

I have been trying hard to find the solution to that error..but cant and need your help..

I am playing with core data, specifically the NSFetchResultsController to populate a table view.
I got 2 VCs, the 1st one (MyViewController) having the table view, the 2nd one (AddToDoViewController) used to add a new cell. The 2nd one s called with a modal segue from a navigation bar button on the 1st one.

when I click save on the 2nd view controllers the app crashes with no error description and only that line as an indication: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

If I delete the 'error = (error)' in the println() just before the first "UIAlertView" the app does not crash anymore...cant understand why...help appreciated, thx!

import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

class AddToDoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let name: String? = self.textField.text

    if name != "" {
        var itemEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)

        if let entity = itemEntity {
            var record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
            var date = NSDate()
            record.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
            record.setValue(date, forKey: "createdAt")
            println("record inserted in managed context")
        }

        var saveError: NSError? = NSError()
        var success: Bool = self.managedObjectContext!.save(&saveError)

        if let anError = saveError {
            println("unable to save record & success = \(success) & error = \(anError)")

            UIAlertView(title: "Warning!", message: "Your to-do item could not be saved", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "").show()

        } else {
            println("Save success with no error")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    } else {
        UIAlertView(title: "Warning!", message: "Your to-do item needs a name!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "").show()
    }

}

@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: It looks like the following line "var saveError: NSError? = NSError()" is the one posing the problem. SaveError is never nil, thus the app is never entering the 1st "else". By replacing that line with "var saveError: NSError?" it works fine. Nonetheless, I do not understand why the program crashed without any explanation on the 1st println.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course var saveError is never nil. You havve instantiated it here: "var saveError: NSError? = NSError()"
Either just decalare it like this "var saveError: NSError?" or leave this part out all together.

Comment: that one I got...still don't know why it crashed on the println where i try to display "anError"...anyway works fine with your suggestion.